# php mySQL echo database content with php and html code

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo

I'm wondering how to achieve this: I have content in a database which I'm retrieving via php. And what I want to work is echo that content but not as plain text but with the php code inside of that string executed and the html code inside being properly displayed. So like I would include a page like

```
    ///File:test.php
    <?php
         //some php code to execute
    ?>
    <div>
        //some html
    </div>
```

So what I want to achieve is the same behaviour as I would do something like

```
    ///php code
    include test.php
```

but instead of including it, I would like to do something like

```
    ///php code
    echo $content; ////$content="string retrieved from database";
```

I know about `eval()` but that only works if the string contains php code only.

**Edit**
The code I want to be executed is not modified by the user in any way. Where is the difference between including a page with php code and hmtl code and doing what I asked for anyway? I would really **much** appriciate if somebody would enlighten me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BAD PRACTICE, don't go this way, don't store code in the DB. google `why not store php code in the database then execute it` You'll find a million thing on this issue.

Comment: Don't go that way. what makes you want to do that ?

Comment: Ditto - that sounds very messy and dangerous.

Comment: appriciate that you're worring about security - still I would very much like it if someone would answer the question anyway

Comment: additionally, I would really tend to say that it is wrong to just generally say that eval() is evil since it very much depends on what I'm trying to achieve-I fully support that it's evil to use when content is in any way modified by the user, but thats not the case here and neither did I say so-furthermore I wonder if I missunderstood the concept of stackoverflow but I thought that it should help people find solutions to their problems. Fair enough some solutions are worse than others and I don't want to force mine but at least a idea on how that solution could look is not too much asked for.

Comment: Some solutions are indeed worse than others, but this falls under the category very bad, hence why nobody is doing it like that. So I ask again : what is it that makes you want to do this ?

Comment: @geeky not silly So to some up I have something like pagecontent stored in the database and I got a flag indicating whether the page contains php code or not. The pages not containing any php are editable by the user, the ones with php code are somewhat special and therefore not editable by the user. So what I've done for the "normal" pages until now is getting the content and echo that onto the page. For the pages consisting of php code I used eval() to execute the code (I always thought that was ok since the user has no chance to edit that).

Comment: what I would like, though, is that page entries in the database which do not just contain php code but also html code to be displayed properly as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [allow_url_include directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) to do that.

Doing so you can write a PHP script that just query the PHP code stored in the database and outputs it. The result will be included in the script including the file, and interpreted again.

Here is a working example. It doesn't read code from the database; to keep it simple I just set a variable with the code, but it would work also if `$a` takes its value from a string stored in a database.

First, you have to set `allow_url_include` to `On`. Open your `php.ini` file and add

```
allow_url_include = On
```

And restart your httpd server.

Now, we'll write two PHP scripts. The first one will be the one querying the source code from database and sending it to `stdout`, named `include.php`. In this example it only declares a simple function:

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: application/x-httpd-php');

  $a = <<<PHP_STR
<?php
  function test() {
    echo 'Hello World!';
  }
?>
PHP_STR;

  echo $a;
?>
```

Note that the `header()` call is needed, otherwise `<?php` and `?>` will be scaped. In your solution, `$a` value will be queried from database instead of being set a constant value, but it will be the same.

Finally, the PHP file that will include this generated code, named `test.php`.

```
<?php
  include('http://localhost/include.php');
?>
<span style="background: lightgreen; color: white; border: 1px solid black;">
  <?php test(); ?>
</span>
```

Now I open `http://localhost/test.php` in may browser and I get `Hello World` in white characters on light green background, surrounded by a thin black border.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer could you please explain a little bit further what you mean?

Comment: I'll edit my own answer to complete it with a working example this noon, if it's ok for you :)

Comment: It is done. However take it just as how could it technically be done, but it's likely there're better solutions than this one for what you want to do.